# Call to action of uibutton that include UIPopOver

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an action of button. In this action i created an UIPopOver then show it. How can i call to action without "button click" action. I tried to call directly but an error : "Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popovers require to be presented from a view which is part of the view hierarchy of the window. Simply put it should be presented from a view whose `window` property is not nil. This should be the case here.

Comment: Resolved. I used NSTimer to call the action after 0.5 second when all componentns are load.